# getting error while showing a user online or offline

Tags: views, database

While setting a user online or offline status with the Views module, I get this error message:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')) < 30, 1, 0) AS users_node_is_online, 1 AS expression FROM node node LEFT JOI' at line 1

How do I fix it?

Comment: It's not clear to me when you get that error. The Views module should not allow you to set the status of a user's account. May you explain with more details what you were doing?

Comment: well, i just wanna show users online status. Is a website is online or offline. To do so i add this status field in views and then this error appear. What to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the field *meh* is referring to is provided by the *user_stats* module. Indeed, once installed it is possible to add that field in a views. There is also a patch for this error on the user_stats issue queue.

Comment: Thanks for your response :) but i am not using Drupal anymore :)